# Proof that $0=x^m - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m-1}{i\cdot x^i}$ always has $m$ real and unique roots

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, roots

I'm trying to learn how to define formal proofs, so I decided to try to prove that the graphs of all polynomials of the form $y = x^m + x^{m-1} + x^{m-2} + \dots + 1$ intersect with their respective derivative graphs at only real values of $x$. This intuitively makes sense following from mean value theorem, but I'm not entirely sure it is correct.

Because setting two polynomials equal to each other turns this into a root finding problem, and the fundamental theorem of algebra implies that all polynomials of degree $n$ have exactly $n$ roots, it turns out I'm proving that the graphs of all polynomials of the form $y = x^m + x^{m-1} + x^{m-2} + \dots + 1$ intersect with their derivative graphs at exactly $m$ real values of $x$.

I started working through a few examples by hand to test this theory ($y = x + 1$, $y = x^2 + x + 1$, $y = x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$, $y = x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$) and noticed that for the case of any given $m$, the problem always seems to reduce to finding the roots of $0=x^m - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m-1}{i\cdot x^i}$, but at this point I'm stuck. How would I prove that for all $m > 1$ with $m = 1$ being a trivial case, $0=x^m - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m-1}{i\cdot x^i}$ always has $m$ real and unique roots?

Comment: In fact, every point of the unit circle is a limit point of the roots as $m \to \infty$.

Comment: Asymptotically, the equation has $m-2$ zeros of the form $(1 - \mathcal{O}(\frac{\log m}{m}) ) \omega$ for $m-1$-th roots of the unity $\omega \neq 1$, the trivial zero $0$, and the real zero of the form $m - \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{m})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m=4$, then

$$0=x^4-\sum_{i=1}^{4-1}ix^i=x^4-3x^3-2x^2-x$$

which has an obvious root, $0$, and so we need to solve

$$x^3-3x^2-2x-1=0$$

But this has $2$ complex roots (see [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-3x%5E2-2x%5E1-1%3D0) for the exact solutions), so your claim is false.

Comment: Hahaha, so the first example after I've done enough to reach a conclusion disproves the conclusion